# incongruencia entre bbdd creadas con pandas y models.py en django

Tags: sql, django, pandas

estoy intentando generar una bbdd en sqlite3 con pandas y hasta ahi todo bien, se genera tal cual la necesito, el problema es que al momento de intentar acceder a esa bbdd a travez de un models creado identico al creado por pandas se rompe y django no logra acceder a esa bbdd.

Tengo el siguiente archivo "output.txt" que fue basicamente generado por una funcion del views.py

```
Interface          Status      Protocol    Description
BE9                down        down        
BE9.1              down        down        
BE9.100            down        down        
Lo0                up          up          
Lo8                up          up          
Lo30               up          up          
Lo100              up          up          ***MERGE LOOPBACK 100****
Lo111              up          up          Configured by NETCONF
Lo200              up          up          ***MERGE LOOPBACK 200****
Gi0/0/0/0          down        down        
Gi0/0/0/1          down        down        
Gi0/0/0/2          admin-down  admin-down  
Gi0/0/0/3          admin-down  admin-down  
Gi0/0/0/4          admin-down  admin-down  
Gi0/0/0/5          admin-down  admin-down  
Gi0/0/0/6          admin-down  admin-down
```

y mediante esa misma funcion hay un fragmento que toma esa info y la traslada a la BBDD:

```
    #Converting txt to Detafrare
    df = pd.read_fwf("output.txt")
    #Depurando df
    df["Description"] = (df.iloc[:, 3:].fillna("").astype(str).apply(" ".join, axis=1).str.strip())
    df  = df.iloc[:, :4]
    #Converting to SQLITE3 database,. If doesn't existe, a nre one will be created
    connection = sqlite3.connect("db.sqlite3")
    #Inserting data into SQLITE database
    df.to_sql(
        name = "Devices_App_interfaces",    #este es el formato de nombre que le da django a los nombres de las tablas.
        con = connection, 
        if_exists = "replace",
        index = False)
    connection.commit()
    connection.close()
    #End Process
```

asi queda visualmente la tabla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

hasta ahi todo perfecto, en paralelo creo una clase en models.py replicando todo este formato:

```
class Interfaces(models.Model):
    Interface = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    Status = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    Protocol = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    Description = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

hasta ahi todo bien, realizo python manage.py makemigrations y python manage.py migrate y todo ok, no lanza ningun problema, pero si intento llamar a algun valor de esa clase del models.py no hace nada, como si no existiera y si por ejemplo agrego la clase a admin.py para verla desde el administrador de django me lanza el siguiente error:

OperationalError at /admin/Devices_App/interfaces/

no such column: Devices_App_interfaces.id

evidentemente Django no logra acceder a esa data y por ende lanza este error, que estoy haciendo mal? existe una mejor o correcta manera de manejar la carga de bbdd de forma externa y acceder a las mismas para mostrarlas en un html?

Saludos!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema era que el campo **id** no existía y lo resolví de la siguiente manera:

```
df.to_sql(
                name = "Devices_App_interfaces", 
                con = connection, 
                if_exists = "replace",
                index = True, index_label="id")
```

es decir se agregaron los campos `index=True, index_label="id"`

aunque también se podría haber solucionado colocandolo siguiente antes del `df.to_sql`, es decir agregando un indice con el campo `id` con una secuencia numerica creciente:

`df[ "id"]=np.arange(len(df))`

por otra parte a la clase generada en el **models.py** debe anidarse una clase **Meta** con la seleccion de `managed = False` lo que hara q django no tome control de esa tabla sino que la considerara autonoma, es decir una bbdd heredada:

```
class Interfaces(models.Model):
    Interface = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    Status = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    Protocol = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    Description = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    
    class Meta:
       managed = False
```

Saludos!

Comment: No olvides [aceptar](/help/accepted-answer) tu respuesta.